# Including json file with include_vars module in ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible

The [include vars module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html) says that a JSON file can be used to load vars. However, when I try to use the module in my playbook, I get a YAML syntax error.

```
---
- hosts: my_hosts
- include_vars: out.json
- tasks:
    command: hostname
```

The syntax error is:

> ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the error you're getting you're misreading it:

> The syntax error is ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Your playbook currently has 3 list items in it (signified in YAML by `-` at the start of the line) which all represent plays in this context.

So Ansible is reading your playbook as containing 3 plays of a single line, one with just a hosts line, one with your include_vars line and one with a task.

Instead you should only have one play here and you should also note that modules (such as [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html)) are used in tasks.

So your playbook should instead look like this:

```
---
- hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
  - name: include vars
    include_vars: out.json

  - name: hostname
    command: hostname
```

Note how the `tasks` attribute of the play has a list of its own, each representing another task.

Comment: fantastic. Im pretty new to YAML so this helped a ton

Comment: cannot we include var for all tasks if referred to all the hosts?